# laravel updated_at default null and on update current timstamp migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, database-migration

Here is what I want to do, when a new row is created, the `updated_at` column should get a `null` value and when that row gets updated, the column should be filled with current `timestamp`

```
Schema::create('city', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->enum('visibilty', ['Visible', 'Invisible'])->default('Invisible');
        $table->string('created_by')->nullable();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->dateTime('created_at')->default(\DB::raw('DATETIME'));
        $table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(\DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
```

Comment: Try `timestamp('updated_at')->nullable()`? Eloquent will update the timestamp on update anyway when saving, so unless you're not using Eloquent, you don't need to add anything else.

Comment: As an option, the Schema Builder has `$table->nullableTimestamps()`, which will create `created_at` and `updated_at` as timestamp fields with null values. Eloquent will still insert the the created_at on creation, and update updated_at on update.

Comment: When you use `eloquent` it will insert current `timestamp` when you create new row,  you should rather use `DB::table('table_name')->insert([])` for creating new row.

Answer (score 0):

$table->timestamp('updated_at')->default(DB::raw('ON UPDATE SYSTIMESTAMP'));

Comment: Could you please add a little bit of explanation to your answer? The only-code-answers are unwelcome at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

`$this->timestamp('updated_at')->nullable()->default(DB::raw('NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));`